# Print data from array php

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, echo

Sorry for noob question, but, how i can print a values of cid1 and cid2 from array?

Simple code here:

```
// Handle the parsing of the _ga cookie or setting it to a unique identifier
function gaParseCookie() {
  if (isset($_COOKIE['_ga'])) {
    list($version,$domainDepth, $cid1, $cid2) = split('[\.]', $_COOKIE["_ga"],4);
    $contents = array('version' => $version, 'domainDepth' => $domainDepth, 'cid' => $cid1.'.'.$cid2);
    $cid = $contents['cid'];
  }
  else $cid = gaGenUUID();
  return $cid;
}


echo "Welcome " . $contents['cid1'] . "!<br>";
```

Comment: have you tried the `print_r` function? http://us1.php.net/print_r

Comment: Either that ^ or a foreach loop would work too.

Comment: i don't understand what parameters i'm must insert in print_r. Can you write, how it must looks like?

Comment: @КонстантинРусанов: Start by reading the link txtechhelp gave you.

Comment: is it just me or does $content not have an index cid1? I only see it having an index of cid - which concatenates cid1 with cid2

Comment: Your `echo` statement is outside your function so it has no access to `$contents`. Either move it inside, or change your function to return `$contents`

Comment: print_r(gaParseCookie()) should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$contents" is in a local scope. You have to write something like this `echo "Welcome " . gaParseCookie() . "!<br>";`
Because "gaParseCookie" function returns value that you need.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
print_r(gaParseCookie());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, this is really what I think you want.

```
    function gaParseCookie() {
      if (isset($_COOKIE['_ga'])) {
        list($version,$domainDepth, $cid1, $cid2) = split('[\.]', $_COOKIE["_ga"],4);
        $contents = array('version' => $version, 'domainDepth' => $domainDepth, 'cid' => $cid1.'.'.$cid2);
        $cid = $contents['cid'];
        echo "Welcome " . $cid1 . "!<br>";
      }
      else $cid = gaGenUUID();
      return $cid;
    }
```

$content[] doesn't have a cid1 index in it. If you want the value from the $cid1 variable, you need to call it from within that function.